# NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification: What's the name Of the Key, that Changed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsnotificationcenter

This code will call the method "defaultsChanged", when some value in UserDefaults changed

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center addObserver:self
           selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)  
               name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
             object:nil];
```

This Code will give me the VALUE that changed

```
- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Get the user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = (NSUserDefaults *)[notification object];

    // Do something with it
    NSLog(@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"nameOfThingIAmInterestedIn"]);
}
```

but how can I get the NAME of the key, that changed??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As others stated, there is no way to get the info about the changed key from the NSUserDefaultsDidChange Notification. But there is no need to duplicate any content and check for yourself, because there is **Key Value Observing (KVO)** which also works with the NSUserDefaults, if you need to *specifically* be notified of a *certain property*:

First, register for KVO instead of using the NotificationCenter:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"nameOfThingIAmInterestedIn"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];
```

don't forget to remove the observation (e.g. in viewDidUnload or dealloc)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"nameOfThingIAmInterestedIn"];
```

and finally implement this method to receive KVO notifications

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                 ofObject:(id)object
                   change:(NSDictionary *)change
                  context:(void *)context 
{
    NSLog(@"KVO: %@ changed property %@ to value %@", object, keyPath, change);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be only applicable when the defaults are changed from inside the app itself, not from the settings bundle.

Comment: @Koraktor: in this specific case you can still add the usual NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification

Comment: @auco things constantly change: in iOS 6 viewDidUnload is deprecated. One should use (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning instead. And thanks for your post ;-)

Comment: @coco: thanks for the hint. That's why I wrote "e.g. in viewDidUnload or dealloc". -didReceiveMemoryWarning is not the best choice as it might never be called, when there's no low memory warning. For iOS6, best place is dealloc.

Comment: I'm using this on the Mac, so it should work there as well.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @Andy yes. Google for "KVO Apple" and you'll find https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: @auco that NSUserDefaults fires KVO?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Articles/ControllerKey-ValueObservingCompliance.html

Comment: This doesn't work if the key doesn't follow the variable naming format because it's an invalid keypath.

Answer (score 2):

There is no data provided in the notification's `userInfo` dictionary, so it looks like you're out of luck unless you want to keep another copy of the data stored in `NSUserDefaults` elsewhere and perform a diff on the two dictionaries.

Comment: Is there another way, to get the name of the changed key?

Comment: Like I said, you can keep a clone of the data stored in `NSUserDefaults` elsewhere and compare the two dictionaries to see what changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom notifications to determine what exactly happened, e.g.:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.event, @"eventObject", nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newEventCreated" object:nil userInfo:options];
```

If it is not an option with userDefaults, then just read all user defaults everytime you get your `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` notification and compair it with previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

just add `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];`

to your `appDidBecomeActive` method and then add

[`[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(settingsChangedListener) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];`

to your `applicationDidEnterBackground`

then use KVO observer as shown above when in the foreground

Answer (score 0):

If your plist ist too big for 'before'-'after' matching, and you simply don't want to add a specific observer to all existing keys (still missing out on newly created keys) you could also swizzle the setObject:forKey:-Method in NSUserdefaults.

Code could look be like this (TODO: error-objects should be handeled properly!)

```
#import "NSUserDefaults+MacOS.h"
#import "JRSwizzle.h"


@implementation NSUserDefaults (MacOS)


+ (void)load {
    [NSUserDefaults jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(setObject:forKey:) withMethod:@selector(zs_setObject:forKey:) error:nil];
    [NSUserDefaults jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(removeObjectForKey:) withMethod:@selector(zs_removeObjectForKey:) error:nil];
}

- (void) zs_setObject:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSObject* oldValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key];
    [self zs_setObject:value forKey:key];
    NSObject* newValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key];
    [[ZSplistWatcher sharedInstance] defaultsChangedForKey:key oldValue:oldValue newValue:newValue];
}


- (void) zs_removeObjectForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSObject* oldValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key];
    [self zs_removeObjectForKey:key];
    [[ZSplistWatcher sharedInstance] defaultsChangedForKey:key oldValue:oldValue newValue:nil];
}

@end
```

(The ZSplistWatcher-Part is just an example code to inform some other Object of the change. Please adapt to your needs)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `dictionaryRepresentation` to obtain the entire copy of `NSUserDefaults` as `NSDictionary`. Then it's a matter of comparing previous values and new values.

`NSUserDefaults` is not KVO compliant, the fact that it may fire some KVO notifications should not be relied upon and is a subject to change apparently.

For example:

```
- (void)setupUserDefaults {
    self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [self.userDefaults registerDefaults:@{ /* ... */ }];

    self.userDefaultsDictionaryRepresentation = [self.userDefaults dictionaryRepresentation];

    [notificationCenter addObserver:self 
                           selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange:) 
                               name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification 
                             object:self.userDefaults];
}

- (void)userDefaultsDidChange:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSDictionary *oldValues = self.userDefaultsDictionaryRepresentation;
    NSDictionary *newValues = [self.userDefaults dictionaryRepresentation];

    NSArray *allKeys = @[ /* list keys that you use */ ];

    for(NSString *key in allKeys) {
        id oldValue = oldValues[key];
        id newValue = newValues[key];

        if(![oldValue isEqual:newValue]) {
            [self notifyObserversForKeyChange:key oldValue:oldValue newValue:newValue];
        }
    }

    self.userDefaultsDictionaryRepresentation = newValues;
}
```