# Detect which Setting was changed in Settings

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

When subscribing to updates from Settings with:

```
NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(
    NSValueTransformer.UserDefaultsDidChangeNotification, Callback);
```

Is there any way to detect which setting it is that changed? Or is there a way to subscribe to a change to only one specific setting?

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there any way to detect which setting it is that changed?
```

After checking the [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaultsdidchangenotification?language=objc) of Apple, it says

> This notification is posted on the thread that changes the user
>   defaults. The notification object is the NSUserDefaults object. The
>   notification **doesn't contain** a userInfo dictionary.

The notification does not provide you a userInfo dictionary to you so I think you can't know which specific setting is changed through this notification.

```
 is there a way to subscribe to a change to only one specific setting?
```

You can have a look at the solutions in [this threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871860/nsuserdefaultsdidchangenotification-whats-the-name-of-the-key-that-changed), I haven't tried it on my side but it may give some ideas to you. I think compare the settings before and after you receive the notification would do it.